# excel vba extract data from website table

Tags: html, excel, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape website and need only 1 value.
How do I retrieve purchase method using code below? see html below

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim IE As Object
    ' Create InternetExplorer Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ' You can uncoment Next line To see form results
    IE.Visible = False
    ' URL to get data from
    IE.Navigate Cells(1, 1)
    ' Statusbar
    Application.StatusBar = "Loading, Please wait..."
    ' Wait while IE loading...
    Do While IE.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 5, Now)
    Loop
    Application.StatusBar = "Searching for value. Please wait..."
    Dim tr As Object, td As Object, tb As Object
    Dim value As String

    Set tb = IE.Document.getElementById("prop_desc clearfix")

    For Each tr In tb.Rows 'loop through the <tr> rows of your table
      For Each td In tr.Cells 'loop through the <th> cells of your row
        value = td.outerText 'your value is now in the variable "value"
        MsgBox value
      Next td
    Next tr

    ' Show IE
    IE.Visible = True
    ' Clean up
    Set IE = Nothing
    Application.StatusBar = ""
End Sub
```

```html
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="prop_desc clearfix"><div class = "span-half">
  <h3>RV Park/Campground for Sale</h3>
  <table>

    

  <tr>
    <td>Number of RV Lots: </td>
    <td>270</td>
  </tr>


  <tr>
    <td>Size:</td>
    <td>
      157 acre(s)
    </td>
  </tr>




    <tr>
      <td>Purchase Method:</td>
      <td>Cash, New Loan</td>
    </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Status:</td>
    <td>
      Active
    </td>
  </tr>


  <tr>
    <td>Property ID:</td>
    <td>966994</td>
  </tr>


    <tr>
      <td>Posted on:</td>
      <td>Jul 10, 2018</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Updated on:</td>
      <td>Jul 10, 2018</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
```

Comment: Set tb = IE.Document.getElementById("prop_desc clearfix")

Comment: Can you provide the URL please and more of the html (for example, include the whole table)

Comment: html here https://docs.google.com/document/d/1J5tDV99IbzucCB_z8QX8lDa4X3ecxQbQOWeVy5B7Irg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: url here https://www.rvparkstore.com/rv-parks/902077--2843-lake-frontage-42-acres-for-sale-in-north-central-us

Answer (score 1):

You can target by class by index and then the td by index

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://www.rvparkstore.com/rv-parks/902077--2843-lake-frontage-42-acres-for-sale-in-north-central-us"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Debug.Print .document.getElementsByClassName("span-half")(0).getElementsByTagName("td")(5).innerText

        .Quit '<== Remember to quit application
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: https://www.rvparkstore.com/rv-parks/902077--2843-lake-frontage-42-acres-for-sale-in-north-central-us

Comment: html here https://docs.google.com/document/d/1J5tDV99IbzucCB_z8QX8lDa4X3ecxQbQOWeVy5B7Irg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: How would I create a group of td elements that I can cycle through it. Just get rid of that number?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

Url https://www.rvparkstore.com/rv-parks/902077--2843-lake-frontage-42-acres-for-sale-in-north-central-us

HTML Here  https://docs.google.com/document/d/1J5tDV99IbzucCB_z8QX8lDa4X3ecxQbQOWeVy5B7Irg/edit?usp=sharing

please use links for more info                jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj